# How do I create a generic property where the type is determined by the compiler?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, properties, abstract

I have searched and cannot find an answer for what I need to do.
I need to have two classes that inherit from a base class, with a generic property. The type of for the property should be determined by the compiler, depending on what type the class is.
Right now, I have this:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass<T>
{
    public abstract List<T> Items { get; set; }
}

public class ChildClass1 : AbstractClass<MyType1>
{
    public override List<MyType1> Items { get; set; }
}

public class ChildClass2 : AbstractClass<MyType2>
{
    public override List<MyType2> Items { get; set; }
}
```

but I still have to specify the type that I want when I create a new AbstractClass object:

```
AbstractClass<MyType1> child1 = new ChildClass1();
```

What can I do so that I do not have to specify the type for the property when I create the instance?

For example:

```
AbstractClass child1 = new ChildClass1();
```

Comment: How exactly do you expect the compiler to infer the generic type `T` of the abstract class?

Comment: That code won't compile, you are not overriding the abstract property.

Comment: Oops, I meant to add override to the Items properties

Comment: If you are not adding any additional functionality, you won't even have to declare the `Items` Property abstract nor to override them. simple `public List<T> Items {get; set;}` is sufficient

Answer (score 4):

Let your `AbstractClass<T>` already inherit from a more general `AbstractClass` where you work without knowing type T at compile time. There you can make use of common methods which do not depend on T at all. You won't be able to access any items based on T directly at this point.

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
   public abstract void MethodOnAbstractClass();
}

public abstract class AbstractClass<T>: AbstractClass
{
    public abstract List<T> Items { get; set; }
}
```

However, you can already define abstract Methods which are to be implemented in the specialised classes which could rely on information from T like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
   public abstract IList GetItems(); //has to be implemented later on
}

public abstract class AbstractClass<T>: AbstractClass
{
    public List<T> Items { get; set; }
    public override IList GetItems() { return Items; }  //Items only visible as objects.

    public AbstractClass() 
    {
        Items = new List<T>(); //Make sure example further down is working.
    }
}

class ChildClass1 : AbstractClass<MyType1> { }
class ChildClass2 : AbstractClass<MyType2> { }
```

The drawback here is, that compared to the Items property, you won't know the type contained in the returned IList of GetItems() at compile time but only at runtime. But it allows you to do things like this:

```
AbstractClass child;

child = new ChildClass1();
int count1 = child.GetItems().Count; 

child = new ChildClass2();
int count2 = child.GetItems().Count;
```

Comment: Mark AbstractClass as _abstract_

Answer (score 2):

OK, as you've found, you can't do that.

> But why?

Because `AbstractClass` isn't a type, where as `AbstractClass<string>` is a type. The "Why?" of this is "because that's the way it works".

You have to tell the compiler what type is replacing `T` at some stage. The way you've defined the class you've said it has to be done upfront when you declare a reference to the class.

You can try other things, but you'll never be able to use the property without specifying the type (unless you want to remove type safety altogether and have `object` everywhere, but I don't think anyone is going to recommend that!)

You could declare an interface

```
interface GenericItems
{
    T GetItems<T>();
}
```

and have an `AbstractBaseClass` that implements that, but there is nothing stopping someone asking for a type that isn't the same as the type `T` the object was implemented on, so really that isn't a solution either

The best way to do it is the way you've designed it, and it only works that way because the compiler needs to know which type of AbstractClass you actually want. It can't infer it from the right hand side of the assignment.

However if you want to treat the various AbstractClass objects polymorphically **AND** you don't care about the typed `Items` property when you do that, then you can create an `AbstractBaseClass` that isn't a generic type.
You put all the polymorphic bits in 'AbstractBaseClass' and then have `AbstractClass<T>` inherit from AbstractBaseClass.

e.g.

```
abstract class AbstractBaseClass
{
    abstract void DoThis();
    abstract void DoThat();
}

abstract class AbstractClass<T>
    : AbstractBaseClass
{
    override void DoThis(){...}
    override void DoThat(){...}
    public T Items{...}
}
```

Then you can do

```
AbstractBaseClass abstractBaseClass = new ChildClass1();
abstractBaseClass.DoThis();
```

You **cannot** do this though

```
AbstractBaseClass abstractBaseClass = new ChildClass1();
abstractBaseClass.Items.Count;  // Compiler error, unknown property or method Items
```

Comment: You could, however, put a `public abstract IList GetItems();` in your `AbstractBaseClass` and then put `public override IList GetItems() { return Items; }` in your `AbstractClass<T>` which would allow you to to the code `abstractBaseClass.GetItems().Count`  This isn't how I would choose to design it, since I prefer to know what type of object is in my collection but it could be done.

Comment: Yeah, you _could_ but I'd rather one of the `DoThis` abstract methods would return the count, if that's what was needed, or do the thing that count is needed for. I know you're saying you wouldn't do it that way, but I'd go _much_ further down the rabbit hole of class design before I'd do it that way.

Answer (score -1):

Take for example this base class:

```
public abstract class Base<T>
{
    public abstract List<T> TheList { get; set; }
}
```

You can make a child class:

```
public class MyClass : Base<string>
{
    public override List<string> TheList
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
```

Your child property still needs to specify what the property type is though. You have to be explicit, you can't use `var` or something.

The compiler can't tell that you want to use a generic argument as the property's type. If you are using Visual Studio, and have a blank child class, it will help you along, but ultimately the language will still require you to give the types of each property.
[image]

This will create the MyClass code you see above.

When you instantiate the class, you don't have to give a generic argument, because you already know that a `MyClass` is going to pass a `string` as the generic argument to `Base`.

```
var mc = new MyClass();
//mc is a MyClass, which inherits from Base<string>
```

But again, you have to tell the class upfront what the types of everything is.

However, if you didn't want to create a child class, you could use the base class directly. Once you remove the "abstracts" from the base class, use:

```
var b1 = new Base<string>;
List<string> b1List = b1.TheList; //TheList is now a string list
```

Yes, you have to set the type when you create the new object, but you don't have to make child classes.

Either way, you have to define the type somewhere. It's up to you if you want to do it in child classes or on a object instantiation.